# ORDER BY with Multiple Counts and SUM()

Tags: mysql, sql

I am struggling to get the syntax correct below. I've tried various unions and joins without success.

I need to  SUM the 3 totals as 'totcount'. The data table is very large and was hoping to find a better way to obtain totcount than a 4th subquery.

```
    SELECT 
    location.*,data.status,
            (SELECT COUNT(data.id) FROM data WHERE data.locid=location.locid AND data.status='NEW') AS newcount,
            (SELECT COUNT(data.id) FROM data WHERE data.locid=location.locid AND data.status='IN-PROGRESS') AS ipcount,
            (SELECT COUNT(data.id) FROM data WHERE data.locid=location.locid AND data.status='COMPLATED') AS compcount
    FROM TP_locations
    LEFT JOIN data ON data.locid=location.locid AND data.status IN('NEW','IN-PROGRESS','COMPLETED')
    WHERE data.status IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY location.locid
    ORDER BY totcount
```

Comment: `ORDER BY newcount, ipcount, compcount, otcount`  first one will take priority and continue in order. If wrong add sample data and create [mre]: https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: What error are you getting? This looks workable, exept for the lack of table aliases.

Comment: I need totcount. the table is large and was looking for a better way to sum what I have rather than doing a 4th subquery to total up (newcount,ipcount,compcount)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query (if I understand the intent) can be simplified to:

```
SELECT 
    location.*,
    data.status, --this is meaningless, it will give you a random one of the 3 possible values
    COUNT(IF(data.status='NEW',1,null)) AS newcount,
    COUNT(IF(data.status='IN-PROGRESS',1,null)) AS ipcount,
    COUNT(IF(data.status='COMPLATED',1,null)) AS compcount,
    COUNT(1) AS totcount
FROM TP_locations
JOIN data ON data.locid=location.locid AND data.status IN('NEW','IN-PROGRESS','COMPLETED')
GROUP BY location.locid
ORDER BY totcount
```

Then you can order by whichever column.

Comment: should be SUM(if....) in each "partial count" adding 1 when true, don't?

Comment: `SUM` will also work, but `COUNT` is a bit better IMO, because the query is suppose to be counting things :)

Comment: Missing ending )  in COUNT